# Setting a friendly name for sockets in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm working with a socket.io project like a chat room. Every time someone sends a message, they send a human friendly name (like "Joseph") along with their name to be shown with their message.

However, I'd like to know if there's a standard way to store these human readable names on the server instead of sending them with every message. In IRC you can set a name with `/nick` command. How can I achieve the same result using socket.io?

Couldn't find anything on [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/).

Comment: Just design a protocol.

Comment: I've done that (by sending the use name along with the message) but I'm curious to know if socket.io has a native way of handling that. It seems like a popular demand.

Comment: No it does not. People can have identical IP addresses for example

Comment: What does having identical IP addresses have to do with mapping socket id strings to friendly names?